# "The prefix 'vat' in XPath cannot be resolved" when validating XML schema instance

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, schema

I am getting the above error when trying to validate an XML document on a schema. Below is a sample from my schema. The prefix 'vat' is used on the FileReference element, but from what I can see, it is being declared in the schema header and has the same value as the targetNamespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
-<xs:schema xml:lang="en" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="targetNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    xmlns:vat="targetNamespace" 
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
    <xs:element name="VATRefund">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>VAT Refund XML file root element.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>   
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FileReference" type="vat:FileReference_Type">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Unique file reference. May be chosen freely as long as it is different from all previous ones.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
```

How can I resolve this error and what could cause it? Below is a sample from the file I use for validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:VATRefundUpload xmlns:ns0="targetNamespace">
    <ns0:FileReference>2064745</ns0:FileReference>
```

Comment: your file should use <ns0:VATRefundUpload xmlns:vat="targetNamespace">

Comment: It's complaining about the prefix "vat" in an XPath expression, so I think the offending code is something different: that is, I think the error is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Please post a ***[mcve]*** if you want help on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that your xsd and the xml have different root nodes -  VATRefund and VATRefundUpload.
If that is a typo, please provide a correct sample input.